# Multiple Threading Thread running one function VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am having a weird issue.

My checkedlistbox has 3 items in it. I check all of the items and click on my button. The button should create the equal number of threads (as the checked items number) and give the index of the checkeditems to a function. The function gives out the checkeditems in the console.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private ThreadList As New List(Of Threading.Thread)

    Private Sub MeineFunktion(ByVal username As String)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
        Console.WriteLine(username)
        'Debug.Print(username)
    End Sub

 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim indexChecked As Integer


        For Each indexChecked In CheckedListBox1.CheckedIndices



            Dim t As Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(Sub() MeineFunktion(indexChecked.ToString))
            ThreadList.Add(t)
            t.Start()


        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

The issue is, the console always gives out

> 1, 1, 2

Instead of

> 0, 1, 2

Why is the first item always ignored?

**What I tried so far**

Changing the byval username as INTEGER, and doing sneding the value like this

```
Dim t As Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(Sub() MeineFunktion(indexChecked))
```

And still encountered the same issue.
Either it has something to do with my threadings, or with the function which does the console writeline (I tried debug print as well).

I can't pinpoint what is causing the issue

Comment: Is this a `console` application? I am asking because I do not see a `module`... but you do print out to the console, which would be in `Visual Studio Console`. Please clarify this. I would preferably assume it's a `winform` application as you are using a `listbox`...

Comment: This is a windows application. I am using the console within my visual studio console to see whether things work correclty.

Comment: You are closing over the iteration variable, which is bad form. `indexChecked` is changing before your first thread starts. You need to save it to a new local *inside* of your `For Each`. Just add something like `Dim CurentIndexChecked As Integer = indexChecked` and use that for your thread routine, instead of `indexChecked`.

Comment: Glorin, thanks, you solved it! Can you elaborate what you mean with closing over iteration variable? maybe in a new post?? That would be super awesome! And I don't exactly get why I had to change it since- when using normal messageboxing with the current index, I would have gotten the correct number/index.

Comment: Your `Sub()...` in your new thread creates a lambda function, which is not executed *until later*. That later time being once the thread is fired up and ready to begin processing the function you gave it. Threads are relatively expensive and take some time to start, so there is a fair delay. Your lambda uses a variable from outside of the lambda itself, so it "captures" that variable for use later, when the function is actually run. It does not capture the *value* of the variable, however. The value will be whatever is in the variable, at the time the code is run.

Comment: Since your code is waiting on the thread to start... and your loop has moved on to its next iteration, the value in `indexChecked` has already changed by the time your lambda is called. Google "closing over iteration variable" if you want to read more. "Access to a modified closure" is a related phrase as well, with the same principal idea.

Comment: Thanks glorin. Where did you learn all that? Did you learn it in some books or did you try yourself and failed at the same part where I failed and got some help? I am trying to model the learning process of other successful coders and trying to figure out whether my learning material was not sufficient enough or is it just me not having enough practical experience

Comment: Everyone is different. I tend to learn more by practical experience. Helps to have many years of that. :) Books can be a good starting point, and can be a good learning point for continued advancement. I tend to read blogs a lot these days. Eric Lippert and Jon Skeet are two bigger names, but there are many out there. Learn concepts, not so much languages. Languages have rules, but the idea you're trying to express is the important part. Language comes later. Above all, programming requires an *extreme* range of knowledge to be truly proficient at, and that just takes time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107869/discussion-between-alexander-mander-and-glorin-oakenfoot).

Answer (score 0):

Each thread needs some time to be created and start running. It seems you are changing *username* before the thread can use it. Try to add a small delay just after each thread start:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim indexChecked As Integer
    For Each indexChecked In CheckedListBox1.CheckedIndices
        Dim t As Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(Sub() MeineFunktion(indexChecked.ToString))
        ThreadList.Add(t)
        t.Start()
        Do
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
        Loop Until t.IsAlive
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a poor workaround as it does not address the *source* of the problem. What if your thread takes longer than your delay to start? You're right back in the same boat.

Comment: @Glorin: To be general I didn't want to modify MeineFunktion(). 10 ms is more than enough. Anyway, you can wait until the thread is completely created: Do Threading.Thread.Sleep(10) Loop Until t.IsAlive

Comment: LMR : 10 ms might be more than enough _for this example_. But what **if** this is just _an example_? What if the OP's real code is doing something that takes time in the beginning of the thread? You don't know that, which is why I have to agree with @GlorinOakenfoot. It is just a temporary workaround.